# how I can play an video from FileChooser in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I hope you to help me to resolve this problem , I try make this code for play video from an `Button` *Open* like option file in all the program but it doesn't work. I don't know what's wrong.

This is my code:

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
            FileChooser.ExtensionFilter filter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("select your media(*.mp4)", "*.mp4");
            chooser.getExtensionFilters().add(filter);
            File file = chooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
            if ( file !=null){

                Media source = new Media(file.getPath());
                MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(source);
                MediaView view = new MediaView(player);
                root.getChildren().add(view);
                player.play();


            }
             else {
                label.setText("vide ");
            }
```

Comment: You should append `file.getPath()` with `file://` i.e. `Media source = new Media("file://" + file.getPath());`

Comment: @ItachiUchiha: Seriously? You do it yourself, even though `File` has a method for this? Try doing it your way with a file that has a space in it's name and you get a exception...

Comment: @fabian I posted the first thing that came to me. I will accept that the answer posted by you is an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the path to [the constructor of `Media`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html#Media-java.lang.String-). This constructor expects a URI string however. Fortunately `File` can be converted to `URI` using [`toURI`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toURI--):

```
Media source = new Media(file.toURI().toString());
```